# Android- Issue found Invalid or inaccurate Permission Form

Tags: android, android-permissions, google-play-console, policy

> Issue found: Invalid or inaccurate Permission Form
> Your app uses sensitive permissions that require a Permissions Declaration Form to be properly submitted. Please check that you have accurately submitted the form in the Play console and that you are only using the allowed permission for your declared use case(s).
> For additional guidance, please review the documentation on how to request app permissions.
> About the Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy
> Requests for permission and APIs that access sensitive information should make sense to users. You may only request permissions and APIs that access sensitive information that are necessary to implement critical current features or services in your app that are promoted in your Google Play listing. You may not use permissions or APIs that access sensitive information that give access to user or device data for undisclosed, unimplemented, or disallowed features or purposes. Personal or sensitive data accessed through permissions or APIs that access sensitive information may never be sold nor shared for a purpose facilitating sale.
> Request permissions and APIs that access sensitive information to access data in context (via incremental requests), so that users understand why your app is requesting the permission. Use the data only for purposes that the user has consented to. If you later wish to use the data for other purposes, you must ask users and make sure they affirmatively agree to the additional uses.
>
> o Permissions and APIs that Access Sensitive Information policy

We had tried to check the policy mentioned in the document and expected some solution to find out the reason why app rejected.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for your question. However it seems like you are not familiar with the guide of Stack Overflow to [How To: Ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please read it and adjust your question accordingly by using the [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77068047/edit) option. Happy coding!